# Bash script- output to one number once t

Tags: command-line, server, bash, scripts

I have a bash script that will echo to a config.txt file. Every time its executed I want it to insert a value as a marker.

Example what I currently have

```
echo userdataOH$((RANDOM % 10))\", >> /usr/local/src/bin/config.txt
```

This will output `userdataOH1-10` but random and value might be the same.

I would like something like

```
echo userdataOH$((Value))\", >> /usr/local/src/bin/config.txt
```

with `Value` being 1-10 and numbers cannot repeat. Is this possible?

Comment: Not repeat meaning ? You want to read `config.txt` and verify that the last value is not the same as the current one?

Comment: So you want to increase `$value` in `config.txt` with each execution of your bash script. You'll either need to extract the last value from `config.txt`, increment it, and append the new value _or_ have the value in a separate file (which is easier but needs a 2nd file).

Comment: Meaning  
 

I have a bash script that will echo to a config.txt file. Every time its executed I want it to insert a value as a marker.

Example what I currently have

echo userdataOH$((RANDOM % 10))\", >> /usr/local/src/bin/config.txt

This will output userdataOH1-10 but random and value might be the same.

I would like something like

echo userdataOH$((Value))\", >> /usr/local/src/bin/config.txt - execute once shows  userdataOH1   . Execute 9 more times, will show userdataOH2,userdataOH3,userdataOH4,etc,etc to 10. The value will not repeat. Once 10,no more value.

Comment: @PerkDuck. Thanks how would I extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

config_file=/usr/local/src/bin/config.txt

last_value=$(tail -1 $config_file 2>/dev/null | perl -n -e 'print $1 if /OH(\d+)",\s*$/' || 0)
next_value=$((last_value + 1))

echo -n userdataOH$next_value\", >> $config_file
```

The `last_value` line extracts the number after `OH` from the last line of the input file (config.txt). If no such number can be found, then it defaults to `0`.

The `echo -n` suppresses the usual `\n` (newline) after echoing. Without it all new `userdataOHNN` lines would be on a separate line instead of being appended to the last line.

I'm not sure about the `\"` in your question. It prints a literal `"`. Drop it from the `echo` and the `perl` command if that was a typo.

Comment: You are welcome. Good to hear.